# Detecting the use of HRESULTs as bools

Tags: c++, winapi, com, static-analysis, hresult

We have a big body of code that was refactored so that stuff which was plain-old C++ is now COM.

I've been spending the last couple of days hunting out places in which we missed the fact that a function that previously returned a `bool` now returns an `HRESULT` (the problem is compound by the fact that `S_OK == false`).

Is there a way to detect places in which an `HRESULT` is being used as a `bool` (and vice versa)?

We're using Visual Studio 2005 (VS8) Professional.

Is there anything other than @Steve's excellent suggestion which doesn't involve installing *Team Edition*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using [Code Analysis for C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3bbz7tz%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)?

If so, you should see

**C6214** per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6dx731.aspx

or

**C6217** per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5aa1ca1.aspx

Also verify your source code (via [#pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28VS.80%29.aspx)) and project options do not disable these or other important warnings.

Comment: Yes we are compiling with /W4 as well as /WX (treat warnings as errors) but we're not getting any such warnings). The links you sent are for VS10 do you know if they are relevant for VS8? (No pragmas are present)

Comment: @Motti - my bad - these come from "Code Analysis for C++" not just regular compiler warnings.  See edit.

Comment: Sounds promising, where do I download it from (I have an MSDN subscription)

Comment: @Motti - it should be built in if you have VS2005 installed under your MSDN subscription.  See here for where to find it in the IDE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yz6c9dy(v=VS.80).aspx. This slows down the build quite a bit so I don't run with it on all the time.

Comment: @Motti - this is in 'Team Edition' - does your subscription cover that?

Comment: Thanks Steve, I'm not sure, I'll check.